# Hover Background with image in front of it

Tags: html, css, image, background, hover

I'm just struggling with basic background hover with image in front of it.

I want my background to by darker on hover, but I don't wanna image in front of it to be also affected. So I want hover background, but at the same time the image in front of it to be still the same.

HTML:

```
<div class="mydiv">
<img class="img" src="Assets/Sources/badge1.png" width="60%" height="60%" >
</div>
<div class="overlay"></div>
```

CSS

```
.mydiv {
  float:left;
  width:49%;
  height:400px;
  margin-right: 1%;
  background-image: url(Sources/bg1.jpg);
  background-color:black;
  background-size: cover;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  position:relative;
}


.mydiv:hover > .overlay {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:relative;
    background-color:#000;
    opacity:0.5;
}
```

Comment: Please, post your jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this by using a pseudo element on `.mydiv` like this you don't need the `.overlay` element at all:

```
.mydiv > img {
    position: relative;
}
.mydiv:hover::before {
    content: "";
    position:absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:#000000;
    opacity:0.5;
}
```